# Manager verbally lied about year end bonus targets. Do I have any recourse?

Tags: germany, bonus

First off: I know I was too naive and should not have believed anything I didn't get in writing.

During my salary negotiation when joining my current employer I received a verbal offer of "x€ per month with an additional payment at year's end as a success bonus subject to some revenue requirements." I was led to believe that those targets are really conservative, and are just to allow the company to save some money if things should really go downhill.
It turned out that was not the case and the revenue target for the last years got set so high we did not reach it, even though the company did extremely well.

As far as I know, there is no way to force the company to pay, but could I sue the manager for damages, if I could prove they were actually misleading me in the negotiation?
If I had not believed this bonus to be really secure I would have demanded a higher salary or chosen another offer.

Comment: "if I could prove"  and "I didn't get in writing." do not get well along with each other.

Comment: Your title is also misleading. Did he lie about salary, or about bonuses?

Comment: You can still demand the bonus you were promised, or otherwise a higher salary to compensate for the lack of bonus. Be prepared to part ways with this employer, though.

Comment: One thing to remember here is that your manager has quite possibly been screwed over here as much as you have (assuming they're not actually the CEO or whoever made the revenue target decision). Consider whether you should be blaming the individual or the company.

Comment: Were you given figures for the revenue targets?

Comment: If you don’t trust your manager, it is time to get another manager.

Answer (score 8):

> I was lead to believe that those targets are really conservative

Were you lead to these beliefs in writing? I"m guessing not.

> could I sue the manager for damages, if I could prove they were
> actually misleading me in the negotiation?

That's a question for a lawyer familiar with employment law in your particular locale.

I'm guessing you have no case.

Answer (score 4):

> if I could prove they were actually misleading me in the negotiation

Were you actually lied to? About facts? So for example did they claim they met the goals and got bonuses every year so far, but actually didn't? Or did they lie about what the goals were?

Because if all that happened was that your manager said "I believe we can easily make those goals", there is nothing you could do, even if you had it in writing.

Your manager believing something is nothing you could sue them for.

If you *were* indeed lied to about facts, and you have proof of that, go see an "Rechtsanwalt für Arbeitsrecht" and let them check your case.

But as a general lesson, "bonus" payments are bogus. Never rely on them. If your salary without the bonus would not be to your liking, find a job that pays you properly, by giving you the salary you want, without shenanigans.

Comment: As someone who has worked in the financial sector, I can assure you that bonus payments are not bogus. They are the meat of any salary in the sector.